# XML from Domino Web Access' ReadViewEntries

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am using Domino Web Access to access a Notes server version 8.5 and retrieve calendar data in XML format. That in itself is not a problem, but i'm having a bit of a problem with the results. My url to Notes looks like

```
http://<server>/mail/<user>.nsf/$Calendar?ReadViewEntries
```

and the resulting XML might look like this:

```
<viewentries toplevelentries="1">
  <viewentry position="1" unid="8EC793F198E10F9A4125E824003E8152" noteid="92A" siblings="1">
    <entrydata columnnumber="0" name="$134">
      <datetime>20110126T100000,00+01</datetime>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="1" name="$149">
      <number>158</number>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="2" name="$144">
      <datetime>20110126T100000,00+01</datetime>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="3" name="$145">
      <text>-</text>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="4" name="$146">
      <datetime>20110126T110000,00+01</datetime>
    </entrydata>
    <entrydata columnnumber="5" name="$147">
      <textlist>
        <text>En lille nisse rejste</text>
      </textlist>
    </entrydata>
  </viewentry>
</viewentries>
```

Is there a way to find out the actual column names instead of namess like $134, $149? I've googled for this and have seen many examples with these symbolic names, but only a few with proper column names. The rest of the XML is of course no problem.

Forgive me if this is a trivial question - I'm a complete novice in the world of Notes.

- turino

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is another (unsupported/undocumented?) url command `?ReadDesign` that will return the Domino XML for the view's design. This includes the column titles as well as the programmatic name for each column.

Comment: ?ReadDesign was just what the doctor ordered.

Answer (score 3):

I think that is the programmatic name of the view column.  You can change that in the last tab of the view properties.

Comment: That is correct.  Note that you should probably create a copy of the $Calendar view and change the columns names there, just so you don't prevent the real calendar view from template updates.  That will also help keep your code working in case the programmatic names change in the next mail template update.

Answer (score 1):

If the column contains a field, then the field name is used for the name for the column and is found in the ReadViewEntries XML in the name="" attribute. If the view column has a formula, Domino Designer generates a unique name like the ones you gave. The person designing the view can replace that $## name with something else, but obviously they didn't do that for the mail template design.
One thing to note, I've found in the past that if you have a formula and you put a field name in the name field on the advanced tab of the column properties then the formula will get replaced by the field you specified.